# Add claims to an already made token

Tags: c#, asp.net, token

I am using the CustomToken example from msdn and messing around with an idea of adding new claims and rebuilding a previously made token or breaking it apart, adding new values and making a new token. I have tried adding new claims to the principal in the relyingparty which didn't work, I tried to rebuild the token and got an error on CustomeSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration 'An item with the same key has already been added' and I have tried close to a dozen different ways that gave no results. Any ideas on how this can be done or am I looking for something that doesn't exist?

Attempt on relying default

```
            if (claimsPrincipal != null)
            {
ClaimsIdentity identity = claimsPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
BootstrapContext bootstrapContext = identity.BootstrapContext as BootstrapContext;
var newclaims = new List<Claim>
    {
       new Claim(ClaimTypes.PostalCode,"56789")
     };
foreach(Claim claim in claimsPrincipal.Claims)
      {
          newclaims.Add(claim); 
      }

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(newclaims, "Name", "UserName", ClaimTypes.Role);

ClaimsPrincipal pass = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessRequest(Request, pass, SimpleWebToken.CustomSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.Current.CreateSecurityTokenService(), Response);

//SimpleWebToken.SimpleWebTokenHandler Added = new SimpleWebToken.SimpleWebTokenHandler();
//Added.AddtoCreatedToken(pass);
```

}

I have also tried adding my own create token which is

```
public SecurityToken AddtoCreatedToken(ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
{
    if (claimsPrincipal == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("tokenDescriptor");
    }

    NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();

    foreach (Claim claim in claimsPrincipal.Claims)
    {
        properties.Add(claim.Type, claim.Value);
    }

    SimpleWebToken token = new SimpleWebToken(properties);
    return token;
}
```

Comment: How about you show us some code, rather than describing what's going on?

Comment: I don't think this is possible because of the security risk. If a malicious user could get a token, he could spoof it and remake the token with more claims, getting rights he shouldn't be able to.

Comment: So then wouldn't the best option be to get the data from the token, deauthorize it or whatever and make a new token?